# custom method_missing ignored if instance is defined via an ActiveRecord association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, method-missing

I have submissions that might be in various states and wrote a method_missing override that allows me to check their state with calls like

```
submission.draft?
submission.published?
```

This works wonderfully.

---

I also, for various reasons that might not be so great, have a model called `Packlet` that belongs_to a meeting and belongs_to a submission. However, I was surprised to find that

```
packlet.submission.draft?
```

returns a `NoMethodError`. On the other hand, if I hard-code a `#draft?` method into `Submission`, the above method call works.

---

How do I get my method_missing methods to be recognized even when the instance is defined via an ActiveRecord association?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you added the draft? method to your respond_to? method for that object?  My guess would be that the issue might arise there.  What happens when you type:

```
submission.respond_to?(:draft?)
```

To fix this, actually write a respond_to? method like this:

```
def respond_to?(method, include_priv = false) #:nodoc:
  case method.to_sym
  when :draft?, :published?
    true
  else
    super(method, include_priv)
  end
end
```

My recommendation would be to implement this without using method_missing instead though, so by doing some meta-programming like this:

```
class Submission
  [:draft, :published].each do |status|
    define_method "#{status}?" do
      status == "#{status}?"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: `submission.respond_to? :draft?` returned true, actually. But I was wondering if there was a truer way of extending a class than overriding `method_missing`. Thank you!